# Regex on an input textbox is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to implement a regex functionality which is, A user can add only one decimal point in a textbox which I mention in my code. I tried like below but it is not working.

**NOTE** The regex is proper, its tried and tested

```
$(function () {
    $('input').on('#txtFiberActlength', function () {
        match = (/(\d{0,2})[^.]*((?:\.\d{0,4})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
        this.value = match[1] + match[2];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to add `event-handler` inside your code,do like below:-

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keyup','#txtFiberActlength', function () {
        match = (/(\d{0,2})[^.]*((?:\.\d{0,4})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
        this.value = match[1] + match[2];
    });
});
```

***Sample example:-***

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('keyup','#txtFiberActlength, #txt2FiberActlength', function () {
      match = (/(\d{0,2})[^.]*((?:\.\d{0,4})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
      this.value = match[1] + match[2];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtFiberActlength">

<input type="text" id="txt2FiberActlength">
```

Comment: ohh, my mistake.. can I also add mulitple `id's` here like this `'#txtFiberActlength', '','', ......` ?

Comment: its not working on my side.. i am able to add multiple `.` this is my textbox. `<input type="text" class="text-center" id="txtFiberActlength" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />`

Comment: @VVVV  you already have  `onkeypress` on your input text-box that's why it's not working.Remove that and check